# What would be the solution for this?

Tags: excel, vba, charts, userform

I have an error to take the data from another workbook for my chart. I already call the workbook and open it, it is so weird because it runs totally well when I was in a practice workbook (without user forms). Part of my code is attached:

The workbook Footballers2020 is already open and active.

```
Dim wsManchester as Worksheet
Set wsManchester = Workbooks("Footballers2020").Worksheets("ManchesterUnited")
    
With FootballChart
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Text = "Players from Manchester United"
        .HasLegend = True
        .ChartType = xlAreaStacked
        FootballChart.SetSourceData Source:=wsManchester.Range("N1:Z34") 'ERROR HERE (DONT TAKE THE DATA)
End With
```

Any possible idea to fix this error? it gives me a chart totally blank.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Answer (score 0):

So I had a play with this I am assuming your set up is:

- two open workbooks
- one called Footballers2020 with a sheet called ManchesterUnited
- another one with a chart in it that we can assign to be FootballChart

I set this up and the following code worked for me:

```
Sub testsub()

    Dim wsManchester As Worksheet
    Set wsManchester = Workbooks("Footballers2020").Worksheets("ManchesterUnited")
    
    Set footballChart = Worksheets(1).ChartObjects(1)

    With footballChart.Chart
            .HasTitle = True
            .ChartTitle.Text = "Players from Manchester United"
            .HasLegend = True
            .ChartType = xlAreaStacked
            .SetSourceData Source:=wsManchester.Range("N1:O34") 'ERROR HERE (DONT TAKE THE DATA)
    End With

End Sub
```

notice specifically I had to add .Chart to the with statement and I removed the FootballChart set source data

If this doesnt solve the issue, please at the chart that is created and let us know the range that it is looking at before and after the code run